# RVM install won't work

Tags: bash, ssh, rvm

Trying to install RVM on my shared Hostgator server. I have jailshelled SSH access. Git is installed and working. When I run the standard RVM install script:

```
bash < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
```

It gets the git repo fine,

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/britt/.rvm/src/rvm/.git/
Enter passphrase for key '/home/britt/.ssh/id_rsa':
remote: Counting objects: 8948, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3901/3901), done.
remote: Total 8948 (delta 5958), reused 7097 (delta 4271)
Receiving objects: 100% (8948/8948), 2.91 MiB | 1354 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (5958/5958), done.
```

but then errors with:

```
: No such file or directory
```

So I checked out what the automated install script is doing, and it's basically running another install script from `~/.rvm/src/rvm/scripts/install`. So I make it executable and try it again:

```
chmod -x ~/.rvm/src/rvm/scripts/install
exec ~/.rvm/src/rvm/scripts/install
```

Which gives me a "permission denied" error:

```
-jailshell: /home/britt/.rvm/src/rvm/scripts/install: Permission denied
-jailshell: exec: /home/britt/.rvm/src/rvm/scripts/install: cannot execute: Permission denied
```

Any ideas??

Comment: By looking at my local ~/.rvm/src/rvm/scripts/install script, I would think you're getting a permission denied error because its trying to altered the $PATH environment variable

Answer (score 0):

I have fired a command

```
source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm
```

and then go with

```
type rvm | head -1
```

and got the output like

> rvm is a function

This works for me. May be this will help you